# What is the purpose of the <circle> html tag?

Tags: html

What is the point of a dedicated tag for a circle when you can just make one easily and more intuitively using `border-radius`? Inline styling is touted as bad practice, so I don't get the appeal of making a circle using non intuitive attributes inside the DOM.

[Here is Optimizely using `<circle>` for semi-transparent grey circles in the landing page](https://www.optimizely.com/homepage/)

There are no SO posts I know of, or MDN references helpful enough about the `<circle>` tag. W3C reference is also unhelpful, hence this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `<circle>` element in HTML. It is [an SVG element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle).

SVG is a vector **graphics** language, so `<circle>` is a perfectly reasonable thing for it to contain.

(HTML allows SVG to be [embedded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#svg) in it).

Comment: So you say that not every `<something>` that appears in the DOM is an element, is that correct? If so, then how can you tell what is a "true" element and what is an accessory element or whatever it is called?

Comment: @BarAkiva — No, I said it wasn't an HTML element. It is an element. It is a DOM element. It is an SVG element.

Answer (score 0):

`<circle>` is SVG element.

The `<circle>` element is used to create a circle:

see here is [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_circle.asp) with Explanation.

Answer (score -1):

circle tag is used as svg element shape. This helps to draw a circle without using image.

You can check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp) for Reference and read in details. :)

Comment: No. The circle element is unrelated to the canvas element.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. :)

Answer (score -1):

Well I would prefer to use `border-radius: 100%;`when I make a circle display. But you can use the `<circle> SVG code` to make it,

more information can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/svg/

Comment: You should avoid having link-dominated answer. Your answer should be at most self-contained. Please refer to [answer].